# Necessities for a D&D map

Tags: world-building, map-making

I am fairly new to D&D but I have always been interested in making maps! 
I was wondering if there are specific elements that must be included on a map for it to be usable.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Please take the [tour] to learn more about how things work around here. Unfortunately, we are a Q&A board that deals with objectively right answers. Discussion topics such as this are off-topic and are better suited to a [traditional forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go).

Comment: Please do not answer in comments.  Work with the OP to get the question opened and then answer in an answer.  Answers in comments get deleted.  I think we can readily retool this into a "101" question/answer, just because it's basic doesn't mean it's too broad per se, it just needs a basics answer.

Comment: Maybe add some of the ideas to your question that you have already.  Terrain/vegetation, roads, towns, buildings, scale/ruler, hex or squares, peoples.  What are the aspects of existing maps are you aware of that you might consider using?  Also, state the objective of the map - the campaign setting, who is going to use it and why?  The scope of the map: Is it a treasure map, a war map, a total map of the known world or small location, a map of what is known to the players?  Also, state your role in the game, are you a game master creating a new world?  Or a player contributing to your group?

Comment: Also, check out: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is far too campaign-specific for us to answer at present. The things a map needs to be usable depend entirely on what you want the map to be used *for*; If you let us know what scale of environment you're trying to map, and what you want your players to be able to locate or navigate to while using it, we'll have a better idea what you need.

Comment: Yeah.  Clarifying this question should be as simple as helping us understand exactly what you're doing - tactical  maps?  World mapping? Player handout maps? Standard "about 3 days of overland travel" adventure maps?